# Bluehost server with laravel app email sending/delieverable issues

Tags: dns, laravel-10, spf, bluehost

**Bluehost server with laravel app email sending/delieverable issues**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="noreply@mydomain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I am using bluehost hosting for laravel app **(with addon domain)**. Mails are working properly only for '@mydomain.com' ids. Emails are not receiving for gmail and other ids. Also there is no any error by the application. A lots of people ar facing this issue (For ref: screenshots are attached). No proper support from bluehost customer support on this. It might be some DNS, SPF etc. kind of issues. ButI could directly edit those settings, it might affect any other places.

Please help me on this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]